# Flask upload and display images from MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, image, flask, flask-mysql

Im working on a website by using Flask. In database my image type blob and Im using flask-mysql library. I want to upload image to the database and display from there but when I trying to display, my output is None in 'goster.html'

Here is my UploadForm:

```
class UploadForm(Form):
   billcontent = StringField("Bill Content")
   bill = FileField("File")
```

and here '/deneme':

```
@app.route("/deneme",methods = ["POST","GET"])
@login_required
def deneme():
   form = UploadForm(request.form)
   if request.method == "POST":
       billcontent = form.billcontent.data
       bill = form.bill.data
       company = get_current_user_company()
       cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
       sorgu = "Insert into deneme(billcontent,bill,company) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
       cursor.execute(sorgu,(billcontent,bill,company,))
       mysql.connection.commit()
       cursor.close()
       flash("{} faturası başarıyla eklendi!".format(billcontent))
       return redirect(url_for("index"))
   return render_template("deneme.html",form=form)
```

and here '/goster':

```
@app.route("/goster")
@login_required
def goster():
   cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
   sorgu = "Select * From deneme "
   result = cursor.execute(sorgu)
   if result>0:
       image = cursor.fetchone()
       return render_template("goster.html",image=image)
   else:
       return render_template("goster.html")
```

deneme.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block middleside %}
{% from "includes/formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ render_field(form.billcontent,class = "form-control") }}
{{ render_field(form.bill,class = "form-control") }}
<button type="submit">Upload Bill</button>

</form>
{% endblock middleside %}
```

goster.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block middleside %}

{{image.bill}}

{% endblock middleside %}
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get from database - `print(image)`. Maybe you get None from database or you display wrong element from `row`. If you have image as bytes then you should convert it to `base64` and put as `<img src="data: base64 ....`>` to display it.

Comment: you could use any database editor/viewer - like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) - to check directly in database what you have in row. Mybe row has no image and problem is when you insert data.